# JDT AST, how to generate a declaration

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

With the help of SO and some documentation I was able to quickly assemble the following code to generate Java source code. But now I am stuck on trying to add a declaration statement. I simply want to create a statement that looks like following

```
Connection con = null;
try{ 
   con = DataSource.getConnection();    
}catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am stuck on the first simplest form of statement, `VariableDeclarationStatement'
This is what I have so far but not sure how can I use variableDeclarationFragment or variableDeclarationExpression.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompilationUnit unit = ast.newCompilationUnit();
        PackageDeclaration packageDeclaration = ast.newPackageDeclaration();
        packageDeclaration.setName(ast.newSimpleName("example"));
        unit.setPackage(packageDeclaration);
        ImportDeclaration importDeclaration = ast.newImportDeclaration();
        QualifiedName name = ast.newQualifiedName(ast.newSimpleName("java"), ast.newSimpleName("util"));
        importDeclaration.setName(name);
        importDeclaration.setOnDemand(true);
        unit.imports().add(importDeclaration);
        TypeDeclaration type = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
        type.setInterface(false);
        type.modifiers().add(ast.newModifier(Modifier.ModifierKeyword.PUBLIC_KEYWORD));
        type.setName(ast.newSimpleName("HelloWorld"));
        MethodDeclaration createMethod = createMethod("helloWorld", new HashMap<String, String>());
        Block block = ast.newBlock();
        //VariableDeclarationFragment variableDeclarationFragment = ast.newVariableDeclarationFragment();
        //variableDeclarationFragment.
        //block.statements().add(ast.newVariableDeclarationExpression(( getConnectionDeclaration()));
        //VariableDeclarationExpression variableDeclarationExpression = ast.newVariableDeclarationExpression(ast.newVariableDeclarationFragment());
        //block.
        //variableDeclarationExpression.
        createMethod.setBody(block);
        type.bodyDeclarations().add(createMethod);
        unit.types().add(type);
        System.out.println(unit);
    }
```

Comment: This is the flaw of procedure-based AST systems. Building ASTs (and auxiliary stuff by hard) is really a pain (and fragile: next release of ADT may break your code).    Program transformation engines offer an alternative:  you can write your code fragment in *source* form, almost exactly as you expressed it in "looks like the following".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse ASTView is a good tool to see how the language tree is set up. When I need to create some code, i write that code first and then look at it in the ASTView. Thuis is the update site I use with Kepler: http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/update-site

I did something very similar to your case lately. Here is the slightly modified code, that should be a good example to fill your `HelloWord.helloWord` method.

```
private Block createStatements(AST ast) {
    Block result = ast.newBlock();

    VariableDeclarationStatement conDeclStmt = createVariableDeclarationStatement(ast);
    result.statements().add(conDeclStmt);
    TryStatement tryStmt = createTryStatement(ast);
    result.statements().add(tryStmt);

    return result;
}

private VariableDeclarationStatement createVariableDeclarationStatement(AST ast) {
    VariableDeclarationFragment fragment = ast.newVariableDeclarationFragment();
    fragment.setName(ast.newSimpleName("con"));
    fragment.setInitializer(ast.newNullLiteral());
    VariableDeclarationStatement result = ast.newVariableDeclarationStatement(fragment);
    return result;
}

private TryStatement createTryStatement(AST ast) {
    TryStatement result = ast.newTryStatement();

    Block body = ast.newBlock();
    ExpressionStatement assignment = createAssignmentStatement(ast);
    body.statements().add(assignment);
    result.setBody(body);

    CatchClause catchClause = createCatchClause(ast);
    result.catchClauses().add(catchClause);

    return result;
}

private ExpressionStatement createAssignmentStatement(AST ast) {
    MethodInvocation invocation = ast.newMethodInvocation();
    invocation.setExpression(ast.newSimpleName("DataSource"));
    invocation.setName(ast.newSimpleName("getConnection"));

    Assignment assignment = ast.newAssignment();
    assignment.setLeftHandSide(ast.newSimpleName("con"));
    assignment.setOperator(Operator.ASSIGN);
    assignment.setRightHandSide(invocation);
    return ast.newExpressionStatement(assignment);
}

private CatchClause createCatchClause(AST ast) {
    CatchClause result = ast.newCatchClause();

    SingleVariableDeclaration exDecl = ast.newSingleVariableDeclaration();
    exDecl.setType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName("Exception")));
    exDecl.setName(ast.newSimpleName("ex"));
    result.setException(exDecl);

    Block body = ast.newBlock();
    ...

    return result;
}
```